# Актуальность изучения Go (Golang) сейчас

Tags: веб-программирование, golang, highload

Вот уже несколько дней не могу найти ответы на свои вопросы. А именно.

1. Можно ли рассматривать Golang, как перспективный язык для изучения (backend), как дополнение к другим или как самостоятельный?
2. Для чего актуально его использовать сейчас и возможно в будущем?
3. Какие перспективы трудоустройства в Украине, России, Европе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Можно ли рассматривать Golang, как перспективный язык для изучения (backend), как дополнение к другим или как самрстоятельный?

Можно

> 2. Для чего актуально его использовать сейчас и возможно в будущем?

Для чего угодно - это вполне себе универсальный язык программирования, с помошью которого можно реализовать практически что угодно. Хотите - делайте бекенды, хотите - [творите приложения под iOS/Android](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile), или, например, [пишите для IoT-устройств](https://gobot.io/)(Arduino и иже с ним)

> 3. Какие перспективы трудоустройства в Украине, Россие, Европе?

Так же как и с любым другим языком программирвоания - на работу принимают программиста не как переводчика с человеческого на непонятный другим машинный язык, а как инжинера способного реализовывать в коде необходимый бизнесу фунционал за приемлемое количество человеко-часов. Каким языком программирования вы при этом будете пользоватся при этом - не важно.

Единственное но - при работе в комманде, нужно общее согласие комманды использовать и поддеживать разработку именно на этом языке. Не всем может нравится Go.

Comment: Угу. Как пример: в моей конторе на Go перевели кодовую базу, которая работала на перле с конца прошлого века. Но - именно в качестве внутренних сервисов, потому как внешнее - C/C++/Java. И было бы странно, если бы го-шники не могли взаимодействовать с остальным миром :)

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный вопрос, где в качестве Golang может стоять какой угодно язык. И не менее стандартный ответ.

1) Программист, делающий ставку на один единственный язык, подобен "специалисту" по кубику Рубика, который умеет собирать только одну его сторону. Ну или можно вспомнить, что говоилось про специалиста и флюс :) В арсенале приличного программиста всегда больше одного языка, и их количество может увеличиваться, даже если основным в данный момент времени является какой-то один.

2) Не нужно забывать, что помимо собственно языков есть ещё и много другого. Например, знание алгоритмов решения задач, знание общих паттернов программирования, да в конце концов банальное умение отлаживать свой собственный код (недостаток последнего явно прослеживается даже по многим вопросам на этом ресурсе). Все эти навыки развиваются как активно, так и пассивно - с освоением новых языков программирования, новых платформ и т.д.

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Но все же, хотелось бы более детально остановится на моих вопросах.